# Alternative to define in-line javascript expressions

Tags: javascript, css, expression, xss

I have been learning web application security penetration testing . The scenario is, there is a cross site scripting vulnerability in a test environment demo web application which is developed for practicing. I have a xss payload which is javascript expressions based :

```
<div style="width: expression(alert(/XSS/))"></div>
```

I know the expressions are deprecated since IE 8 .It works fine in IE7.  So , when i input above payload , Web app returns with

```
<div></div>
```

It rips off all other attributes and values. But when i alter the payload like

```
<div style="width: expression'(alert(/XSS/))'">
```

Its not a valid payload means it won't execute. So, i am trying to figure out if there is any alternative to define expression in in-line style attribute like if we can place something else other than single_quote which won't break the code . Or if there is any other way to execute javascript via style attribute.

Comment: Is there any escaping of your injected input?  If not, you can just close the style attribute and tag with `">` and inject a `<script>` tag there.

Comment: Yes, Escaping is there .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expression()` is the only way to dynamically specify html node attributes. It takes any valid [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72bd815a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) expression as an argument. So technically there is no way to execute javascript via style attribute on an html node (JScript !== javascript).

The reason this functionality doesn't exist, (or has been deprecated) is because it creates a pretty big security vulnerability. If you want to have dynamic html elements, you'd tackle that with css, specifically through [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). But if you want to go down this path, try checking out the [`expression()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

In javascript (JScript as well), `()` invoke a function. So throwing `'` or `"` after an expression name, before invoking it, is invalid syntax. There's probably something else you can place besides "single_quote" which won't break the code, but you wouldn't place it before the `()`. Try looking up JScript syntax. Here's one [last resource](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dynproperty2.shtml) that may help.

Comment: Thanks for the resources and quite great information. Style attribute is all i have to inject through. I will wait for some more time if someone else can help with it, else will mark your answer as correct and +100.